# How to change [object object] from firebase to a string?

Tags: javascript, database, string, firebase

I get an object from my code

```
       const username = await firebase
        .database()
        .ref("users/" + authUser + "/name")
        .once("value")
        .then(function(snapshot) {
          return snapshot;
        });
```

Its value is "testname". Its logging everything correct to console. But if I try to reuse my username for example in

```
      const url = `https://url.com/users/${username}/${authUser}/posts.json?auth=${token}`;
```

I get in my console.log

```
https://url.com/users/[object Object]/...
```

I am pretty new to firebase and JS but I think I have to transform my object to a string? How to achive this?

Comment: JSON.stringify(object)?

Comment: Got it now via      
 

    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(username);

But it return "testname". Do you know how to get rid of the ""?

Comment: What is the use case of removing this ""?

Comment: I am writing via REST Api to my firebase with the username.
The structure is now /users/"testname"/posts but should be "users/testname/posts

Comment: yourString.substring(1, yourString.length-1) or go with yourString.slice(1, -1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to convert your object to a string

```
JSON.stringify(object)
```